# ¿Is it possible to trigger a beacon event via its MAC address using Android Beacon Library if i have the same UUID for every beacon?

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

I am developing a museum type application that when detecting a beacon at **a certain distance** near to a point of interest, shows me relevant information about it.

**My problem is that all my beacons come by default with the same UUID**, therefore I have no way to distinguish them by means of a:

```
if (beacon.getId1().toString().equals("iBeacon UUID here"){}
```

since as the estimote library says, there are only three ways to ranging a beacon form a region (https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/203776266-What-is-a-beacon-region-):

> **1. With only UUID:** it consists of all beacons with a given UUID. For example: a region defined with default Estimote UUID would consist
> of all Estimote Beacons with unchanged UUID.
>
> **2. With UUID and Major:** it consists of all beacons using a specific combination of UUID and Major. For example, all Estimote
> Beacons with default UUID and Major set to 13579.
>
> **3. With UUID, Major and Minor:** it consists of only a single beacon (Estimote Cloud prevents having two beacons with the same IDs). For
> example, one with default Estimote UUID, Major set to 13579 and Minor
> set to 2468.

I had the idea to use the next instance:

```
if(beacon.getBluetoothAddress().equals("iBeacon UUID here")){}
```

instead of the above.

But the result of using this instance is negative and the beacons are not detected correctly if i use the function "getBluetoothAddress()".

This is an example of code using "beacon.getId1().toString().equals":

```
beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
           @Override
           public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
              if (beacons.size() > 0) {

                  String current=" ";
                 //EditText editText = (EditText)RangingActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.rangingText);
                 Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                  Log.e(TAG,firstBeacon.toString());
                  String x =firstBeacon.getId1().toString();
                  Double d=firstBeacon.getDistance();
                 // x=x.substring(24);
                 Log.e("Ranging","The first beacon " + firstBeacon.getId1().toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");

                  if(x.equals("00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff") && k1!=1 && d< 5.0)
                  {
                      x = current;
                          monolisa_fragment fragment = new monolisa_fragment();
                          getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout, fragment).commit();

                      k2=0;k3=0;k4=0;k1=1;

                  }

                  else if(x.equals("00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff") && k2!=1 && d< 5.0)
                  {
                      Log.e("Sure",x.toString());
                      kohinoor fragment=new kohinoor();
                      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout,fragment).commit();
                      k1=0;k3=0;k4=0;k2=1;

                  }

                  else if(x.equals("00112233-4455-6677-8899-aabbccddeeff") && k3!=1 && d< 5.0){
                      allanhills fragment =new allanhills();
                      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.framelayout,fragment).commit();
                      k1=0;k2=0;k3=1;k4=0;
                  }

              }
           }

        });

        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
    }
```

but i can't use "beacon.getId1().toString().equals" because my UIID beacons, have the same UUID. And i can't use "getBluetoothAddress()", because fails and because how the estimote library says, i need the UUID of every beacon, but in my case, every beacon have the same UUID.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to do this.

Two points:

1. It is common for every beacon to have the same UUID, but for the major and minor (also known as ID2 and ID3) to vary.  You might consider distinguishing them by those fields if they are different.  This is the standard practice.
2. If you can't do this for some reason, you can use the MAC address to distinguish your beacons.  Simply set `Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true)`.  This will result in you getting multiple detections for an identical identifier so long as the MAC address is different.

When it comes to searching for beacons by MAC Address, you will need to use Ranging APIs like this:

```
Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);
Region region = Region("all-beacons-matching-uuid", "2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6", null, null); // Replace with your UUID
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

If you only want to discover one beacon with a specific MAC address you can do so like this:

```
Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced(true);
Region region = Region("only-one-beacon-matched-by-mac", "00:11:22:33:44:55"); // replace with your beacon's MAC address
beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)
```

Then read the MAC like this:

```
public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
  for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
     if (beacon.getHardwareAddress().equals("00:11:22:33:44:55") {
        Log.d(TAG, "This is the beacon I am looking for.");
     }
  }
}
```

You'll need to know the MAC address of each of your beacons to do this.  You can use an off-the-shelf scanner like my [BeaconScope](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.davidgyoungtech.beaconscanner&hl=en_US) to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply David. I am extremely grateful to be able to use your open source android beacon library. I really was missing this, that you have explained to me to know how to solve my problem since both the UUID and the values of major and minor are the same in my beacons and the only data that differentiates them is the MAC address.

I will try to do it in the way you have indicated and I will carry out a series of tests and later i'll publish the results here.

I repeat, I am enormously grateful both for your response and for your work on beacons.

A cordial greeting. Regards

Comment: Hi! I have been doing tests and indeed this is the correct way to implement this using the mac address of the beacons. I was missing the line of code "Beacon.setHardwareEqualityEnforced (true);" It has been to use it and start working.

I am very grateful for the help, I cannot upvote this answer because my reputation is less than 15, but this is the solution that solves my problem.

Comment: Glad this helped.  You should be able to click the check mark to accept the answer even if you cannot upvote.  Doing so will help others who have the same problem find the solution.